# "Stop To" vs "Stop On"; Which will be correct in below sentence?

Tags: prepositions

Context:

1: Will this step of government put stop *to* all those criminal activities?

2: Will this step of government put stop *on* all those criminal activities?

The second sounds right according to me but on internet in many contexts, "to" seems to be correct.

Comment: I would not use "sounds right" as a sole justification. Anything else?

Answer (score 1):

The first one is (almost) correct, and while I can think of a much more limited example where the second one would work (see below), it is incorrect as you have used it.

I say the first one is almost correct because it isn't "put stop to...," but rather, "put a stop to..."

So, to use your example, "Will the government put a stop to all those criminal activities?"

The only example I can think of where "put a stop ON" would be used is in reference to a non-cash payment that has been issued and subsequently withdrawn: "I paid for the tickets, but decided to put a stop on my check when I didn't receive them."

This would mean that the buyer sent the check to the seller, but then called his/her bank and had them block the receipt of this check by the seller when the buyer did not receive the tickets as promised from the seller.

Comment: I wonder why someone would downvote this. It's a correct and useful answer to a reasonable question. Maybe I'm missing some hidden flaw?

Comment: @NathanTuggy I agree. +1 from me.